# how to set width 100% always

Tags: html, css

I wrote html & css like below.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin : 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
}

aside {
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 200px;
}

main {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.content {
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>My test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        header
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <aside>side menu</aside>
        <main>
            <div class="content">
                content
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then, I resize browser size less than 700px(aside width + content width.) width.

as result, header width is less than contents like below(scroll to the far right).
I guess this because of contents has `min-width` property.
Then, I want to manage header width based on contents width.
do you know any idea?
thanks.

[image]

Comment: So, what is the question ? You are correct the since you have two elements with `min-width` 200 and 500, they cannot fit side-by-side when the available space is less than 700. How do you want to handle it visually ? You could give your container a min-width of 700 and that would stop the breaking, but it would not fit as a whole. An alternative is to use media queries to re-style parts of the page when the viewport is less than 700.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution. But if you want to maintain a `min-width` of `200px` for the aside and a `min-width` of `500px` for the content (with `10px` padding), you can provide a `min-width` of `720px` (200px+500px+10px+10px) for the header.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin : 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 720px;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
}

aside {
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 200px;
}

main {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.content {
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>My test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        header
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <aside>side menu</aside>
        <main>
            <div class="content">
                content
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @VaisakhPredeep thanks!! but my content width are changing frequently. For example, if content is article that min-width is 300px,  and if content is other, width is 200px. I want to set header min-width based on changed width of contents

Comment: @sho If the content width is changing frequently, you might need to make it responsive. I would suggest using '%' width value for the content or leaving the width as the default value 'auto' without using a `min-width` value.